# How can you have both PUT and POST routing attributes on a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-put

PUT and POST do a very similar thing in REST. The assumption being a POST means *create a new entry* and PUT means *update an existing entry*.

I had always assumed you could only have a single routing attribute on a controller action method, but now I have a situation where I want a method to respond to either `HttpPost` *or* `HttpPut`.

### Update:

Tried a few variations and the actions were not hit if more than one routing attribute was applied. Like these:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Include(int id, int order, int parent)
{
    return "...some result";
}

[HttpPost, HttpPut]
public ActionResult Include(int id, int order, int parent)
{
    return "...some result";
}
```

The question now is: How do you respond to both PUT and POST requests in the same controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's builtin way to do that. Use [AcceptVerbsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Put)]
public ActionResult Include()
{
}
```

Comment: I had never come across that attribute before. Tested it and it works a treat. Excellent! :)

Comment: Actually if you take look at sources, HttpPost and HttpPut are kind of shortcut to AcceptVerbs, and are implemented using AcceptVerbsAttribute